# Correcting (removing) adjustwidth's vertical spacing

Tags: spacing, lists, indentation

Consider the following example that uses [`changepage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage)'s `adjustwidth` to set a single paragraph at 80% of the text width (on the left). Compare this to the use of `\parshape` (on the right):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{changepage,lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{changepage,lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{adjustwidth}{0pt}{.2\textwidth}
\hspace*{\parindent}\lipsum[2]
\end{adjustwidth}

\lipsum[2]

\clearpage

\lipsum[1]

\parshape 1 0pt .8\textwidth
\lipsum[2]

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

How can I adjust the vertical spacing introduced by `adjustwidth` so that it matches that of the `\parshape` output?

I understand that `adjustwidth` sets its contents in a list (see [`changepage.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/changepage/changepage.tex)), and lists naturally have some gap above/below it. However, `\topsep` is set to zero (`\z@`) already, so I'm not sure where these lengths come from/how to remove them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The extra space comes from `\partopsep`. You can set `\partopsep` to `0pt`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{changepage,lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{changepage,lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{adjustwidth}[2]{%
  \begin{list}{}{%
    \partopsep\z@%
    \topsep\z@%
    \listparindent\parindent%
    \parsep\parskip%
    \@ifmtarg{#1}{\setlength{\leftmargin}{\z@}}%
                 {\setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}}%
    \@ifmtarg{#2}{\setlength{\rightmargin}{\z@}}%
                 {\setlength{\rightmargin}{#2}}%
    }
    \item[]}{\end{list}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{adjustwidth}{0pt}{.2\textwidth}
\hspace*{\parindent}\lipsum[2]
\end{adjustwidth}

\lipsum[2]

\clearpage

\lipsum[1]

\parshape 1 0pt .8\textwidth
\lipsum[2]

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Or, with the help of `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{changepage,lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{changepage,lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{adjustwidth}{\partopsep0pt}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{adjustwidth}{0pt}{.2\textwidth}
\hspace*{\parindent}\lipsum[2]
\end{adjustwidth}

\lipsum[2]

\clearpage

\lipsum[1]

\parshape 1 0pt .8\textwidth
\lipsum[2]

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to further reduce the vertical space?